# How to parallelize matrix sorting for loop?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, parallelism-amdahl

I am trying to parallelize a **`for(){...}`** loop, using OpenMP, which takes a number of "lines" **`N`** of a "*table*" **`N*M`** and sorts each line in an ascending order.

I added **`#pragma omp parallel`**, **`#pragma omp for schedule`**   directives, but don't see any changes, as if it does nothing at all.

Here is full program:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <iostream>

double GetTime() {
   struct timeval clock;
   gettimeofday(&clock, NULL);
   double rez = (double)clock.tv_sec+(double)clock.tv_usec/1000000;
   return rez;
}

void genMatrix(int *A, int N, int M) {
   // Generate matrix
   for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<M; j++) A[i*M+j] = (int)((double)rand()/RAND_MAX*99) + 1;
   }
}

int main() {
   srand(time(NULL));
   int N = 4800;
   int M = 6000;
   int *A = new int[N*M];
   int t, n;
   genMatrix(A, N, M);

      double t_start = GetTime();

       #pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp for schedule     
   for (int k=0; k<N; k++) {
      for (int i=0; i<M-1; i++) {
         for (int j=0; j<M-1; j++) {
            if (A[k*M+j] > A[k*M+j+1]) {
               t = A[k*M+j];
               A[k*M+j] = A[k*M+j+1];
               A[k*M+j+1] = t;
}}}}}
             double t_load = GetTime();
    //    Print matrix

  //  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    //   for (int j=0; j<M; j++) {
      //    printf("%3d", A[i*M+j]);
     //  }
      // printf("\n");
   // }
       printf("Load time: %.2f\n", t_load - t_start);
    system("pause");
}
```

What is wrong and how should I add parallelization with OpenMP in this case?

Also, don't know why, but when trying to print the matrix **`A`** with big numbers
( like `int N = 480;int M = 600;` ), some values are not sorted.

Is it a printing problem?

Comment: Missing pragma omp parallel and completion of schedule clause.  t needs to be declared local to thread (thus private)

Comment: @tim18 nvm, You are right. except for parallel word.

Comment: @tim18 thank you. But quite not understand why time reduced only ~twice. expected better optimization

Comment: Can 2D bubble sort be panellized this way? aren't the loops depending on each other and will therefore fail???

Comment: @Surt outer loop sorts lines, two inner loops sort each line looping till all values are sorted for sure. (a little bit hard work there, but its for sake of demonstrating how parallelization can optimize time.

Answer (score 1):

### There are three distinct things, sine-qua-non, to go `omp parallel`:

**A** ) - the algorithm has to be correct
**B** ) - the algorithm has to use resources efficiently
**C** ) - the algorithm has to spend less on add-on overhead costs, than it receives from going `omp`

### Fixing `A`) and after some slight experimentation on `B`) and `C`):

one may soon realise, that the costs demonstrated under **B** ) and **C** ) for a **`rand()`** processing are way higher, that any benefit from whatever naive or smarter matrix-coverage mapping onto resources ( here, a singular-engine, as any type of concurrency has to re-propagate a new state of the `rand()`-source-of-randomness across all the concurrent uses thereof, costs way more than it could deliver in concurrently operated matrix-coverage ( plus naive cache-line un-aware crossing of the matrix does not help either ).

The best results ( without optimising the `myOMP_SCHEDULE_CHUNKS` ):

```
/*
-O3 private( ..., i, j ) omp single
MATRIX.RAND time:     3 191 [us]     3 446 [us]    3 444 [us]     3 384 [us]      3 173 [us] 
MATRIX.SORT time:    96 270 [us]    98 401 [us]   98 423 [us]    95 911 [us]    101 019 [us] @( 3 ) = OMP_THREADS in [ 5 ] OMP_SCHEDULE_CHUNKS
*/
```

The global view:

```
/* COMPILE::    -fopenmp
 * 
 * MAY SHELL::  $ export OMP_NUM_THREADS = 3
 *              $ export OMP_DISPLAY_ENV = 1
 *                                                                       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47495916/how-to-parallelize-matrix-sorting-for-loop
 */

#include <omp.h>
#define myOMP_SCHEDULE_CHUNKS   5               // OMP schedule( static, chunk ) ~ better cache-line depletion
#define myOMP_THREADS           4

/*
$ ./OMP_matrix_SORT

MATRIX.RAND time:   187 744 [us]   234 729 [us]   174 535 [us]   254 273 [us]   122 983 [us]
MATRIX.SORT time: 1 911 310 [us] 1 898 494 [us] 2 026 455 [us] 1 978 631 [us] 1 911 231 [us] @( 3 ) = OMP_THREADS

MATRIX.RAND time:                                   6 166 [us]     6 977 [us]     6 722 [us]  
MATRIX.SORT time:                               2 448 608 [us] 2 264 572 [us] 2 355 366 [us] @( 3 ) = OMP_THREADS in [ 5 ] OMP_SCHEDULE_CHUNKS

MATRIX.RAND time:                                   6 918 [us]    17 551 [us]     7 194 [us]
MATRIX.SORT time:                               1 774 883 [us] 1 809 002 [us] 1 786 494 [us] @( 1 ) = OMP_THREADS

MATRIX.RAND time:                                   7 321 [us]     7 337 [us]     6 698 [us]
MATRIX.SORT time:                               2 152 945 [us] 1 900 149 [us] 1 883 638 [us] @( 1 ) = OMP_THREADS

MATRIX.RAND time:                                  54 198 [us]    67 290 [us]    52 123 [us]
MATRIX.SORT time:                  759 248 [us]   769 580 [us]   760 759 [us]   812 875 [us] @( 3 ) = OMP_THREADS

MATRIX.RAND time:                    7 054 [us]     6 414 [us]     6 435 [us]     6 426 [us]
MATRIX.SORT time:                  687 021 [us]   760 917 [us]   674 496 [us]   705 629 [us] @( 3 ) = OMP_THREADS

-O3                              
MATRIX.RAND time:     5 890 [us]     6 147 [us]     6 081 [us]     5 796 [us]     6 143 [us] 
MATRIX.SORT time:   148 381 [us]   152 664 [us]   184 922 [us]   155 236 [us]   169 442 [us] @( 3 ) = OMP_THREADS in [ 5 ] OMP_SCHEDULE_CHUNKS

-O3 private( ..., i, j )
MATRIX.RAND time:     6 410 [us]     6 111 [us]     6 903 [us]     5 831 [us]     6 224 [us]
MATRIX.SORT time:   129 787 [us]   129 836 [us]   195 299 [us]   136 111 [us]   161 117 [us] @( 4 ) = OMP_THREADS in [ 5 ] OMP_SCHEDULE_CHUNKS

MATRIX.RAND time:                    6 349 [us]     6 532 [us]     6 104 [us]     6 213 [us]
MATRIX.SORT time:                  151 202 [us]   152 542 [us]   160 403 [us]   180 375 [us] @( 3 ) = OMP_THREADS in [ 5 ] OMP_SCHEDULE_CHUNKS

MATRIX.RAND time:     6 745 [us]     5 834 [us]     5 791 [us]     7 164 [us]     6 535 [us] 
MATRIX.SORT time:   214 590 [us]   214 563 [us]   209 610 [us]   205 940 [us]   230 787 [us] @( 2 ) = OMP_THREADS in [ 5 ] OMP_SCHEDULE_CHUNKS

 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <iostream>

long GetTime() {                                    // double GetTime()
   struct timeval clock;
   gettimeofday( &clock, NULL );
   return    (long)clock.tv_sec  * 1000000          // in [us] ( go (long) instead of float )
         +   (long)clock.tv_usec;                   // 
/* double rez = (double)clock.tv_sec
 *            + (double)clock.tv_usec / 1000000;
 *         // + (double)clock.tv_usec * 0.000001;   // NEVER DIV
   return rez;
   */
}

void genMatrix( int *A, int N, int M ) {            // Generate matrix
   register int i, iM, j;

   #pragma omp parallel
   for (              i  = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
                      iM = i * M;

/* for ( register int i  = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
         register int iM = i * M;
         */
      // #pragma omp parallel                                               //  234 729 [us]
      // for ( register int j = 0; j < M; j++ )

      // #pragma omp parallel for schedule( static, myOMP_SCHEDULE_CHUNKS ) //  122 983 [us] @( 3 ) = OMP_THREADS ~~~  v/s   6 698 [us] @( 1 ) = OMP_THREADS
      //                                                                    //                                         v/s   5 796 [us] @    NON-OMP
         #pragma omp single                                                 // ~~ 3 191 [us]
         for (          int j = 0; j < M; j++ )
                      A[iM +j] = (int)( (double)rand() / RAND_MAX * 99 ) + 1;
                   // A[i*M+j] = (int)( (double)rand() / RAND_MAX * 99 ) + 1;
   }
}

int main() {
    srand( time( NULL ) );
    int  N   = 480;                                 // 4800; ~ 100x faster outputs
    int  M   = 600;                                 // 6000;
    int  Mb1 = M - 1;
    int *A   = new int[N*M];

    omp_set_num_threads( myOMP_THREADS );

    long long int  t_start = GetTime();

    genMatrix( A, N, M );

    long long int  t_load = GetTime();
    printf( "MATRIX.RAND time: %lld [us]\n", t_load - t_start );

    register int thisB,
                 this1,
                 next1,
                 t, i, j;

    t_start = GetTime();                        // double t_start = GetTime();

// for ( register int k = 0; k <  N;   k++ ) {

// #pragma omp parallel
// #pragma omp parallel for schedule( static, myOMP_SCHEDULE_CHUNKS )                                           // schedule( type, chunk ):
// #pragma omp parallel for schedule( static, myOMP_SCHEDULE_CHUNKS ) private( thisB, this1, next1, t )         // schedule( type, chunk ):
   #pragma omp parallel for schedule( static, myOMP_SCHEDULE_CHUNKS ) private( thisB, this1, next1, t, i, j )   // schedule( type, chunk ):
   for ( int k = 0; k <  N;   k++ ) {
       thisB =  k*M;

       if ( omp_get_num_threads() != myOMP_THREADS ) {
            printf( "INF: myOMP_THREADS ( == %d ) do not match the number of executed ones ( == %d ) ", myOMP_THREADS, omp_get_num_threads() );
       }
    //--------------------------------------------------// -------------SORT ROW-k
    // for (      register int i = 0; i <  Mb1; i++ ) { //    < M-1; i++ ) {
    //     for (  register int j = 0; j <  Mb1; j++ ) { //    < M-1; j++ ) {
       for (                   i = 0; i <  Mb1; i++ ) {
           for (               j = 0; j <  Mb1; j++ ) {      

               this1 = thisB + j,
               next1 = this1 + 1;

               if ( A[this1] >  A[next1] ){             // A[k*M+j  ] >  A[k*M+j+1] ) {
                    t         = A[this1];               // t           = A[k*M+j  ];
                    A[this1]  = A[next1];               // A[k*M+j  ]  = A[k*M+j+1];
                    A[next1]  = t;                      // A[k*M+j+1]  = t;
               }
           }
       }
    //--------------------------------------------------// -------------SORT ROW-k
   }

   t_load = GetTime();                                  // double t_load = GetTime();
/* Print matrix
  //
   for (    int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
      for ( int j = 0; j < M; j++ ) {
            printf( "%3d", A[i*M+j] );
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
 //
   */
   printf( "MATRIX.SORT time: %lld [us] @( %d ) = OMP_THREADS in [ %d ] OMP_SCHEDULE_CHUNKS\n",
            t_load - t_start,
            myOMP_THREADS,
            myOMP_SCHEDULE_CHUNKS
            );
// system( "pause" );
}
```